# I have hard to see when I would use date.parse and date.utc

Tags: javascript

The Date object provides method Date.parse and Date.UTC that can be called without creating a new Date object. Date.parse receives as its argument a string representing a date and time and return the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1,1970 and the specified date and time.

Date method UTC return the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1,1970 and the date and time specified as its argument.

So my question is when do anyone need to use cheese. I have hard to the usefulness

//Tony

Comment: Cheese? Parse is used any time you need to parse a date string- its use seems self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

**[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** assumes local time if not specified. It gets the date in your machine local time

**[Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)** however gets the UTC time and takes additional parameters that you can use to pass hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. *UTC takes comma-delimited date parameters and returns the number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, universal time and the time you specified.*

Answer (score 0):

First difference between them is their arguments list.

**Date.UTC()**

```
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, millisec);
```

**Date.parse()**

```
Date.parse(datestring);
```

Then, the other difference is that `parse()` uses *local time*.